# Is there any way to set XML comment to local variables?

Tags: c#

Simple: Is there any way to set XML comment to local variables in Visual Studio?  Specially looking for the following (which will **not** work in any version of VS)..

### Such as:

```
/// <summary>
/// Perform editing of multiple HexCells in the HexGrid.
/// </summary>
void EditCells(HexCell center)
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the horizontal center of the a cell that I'm working with.
    /// </summary>
    var centerX = center.coordinates.X;

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the vertical center of the a cell that I'm working with.
    /// </summary>
    var centerZ = center.coordinates.Z;

    ...
```

---

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: If answer is no, then VS is surly lacking!

Comment: How is it lacking? If you want to document your implementation details (and I can't imagine why anyone would when they can just share the source code directly), just put it in the method doc or something. And there's nothing stopping you from using regular comments.

Comment: Just to clarify:  I am not looking for comments in the final product -- not like a released assembly, but more in just initially displayed comments.  For example, if you hover over a class definition, you will see these comments.  However, hover over a local variable, nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no sense in XML-documenting your local variables.

XML documentation provides information for those who **use your assembly / class / method**. It is not supposed to be read through code. They cannot access local variables and therefore they won't be able to access this documentation.

If you want to make a comment for those who **read or maintain your code**, then you can just use simple comments.

Comment: True, however, sometimes it is quite useful to have this capability!  Some methods might get quite long (especially if adding comments to help others understand code).  I would like to make things as Verbose as possible!

Comment: Sometimes methods (no matter what language) will get beyond 20 lines (heaven forbid)... However it is just a fact of life!

Comment: @Silverten XML comments would make these methods even longer :) By the way, if you feel like your method is too long and unmaintainable, then you may want to refactor it.

Comment: Plus, VS pops up a descripton for non-local stuff.  Interanal Documentaion **is** always good.  Why limit to that any way?
This is not a new question for me anyway.

Comment: @Silverten: If it's not immediately obvious from 1) the variable name, and 2) the surrounding context what the variable is meant for, you're doing it wrong. It doesn't matter how long or short the method body is. Frankly nobody even uses regular line comments to document their local variables either for this reason.

Comment: I disagree – there is sense in documenting these things. Sometimes code modules do go beyond the screen boundaries.  Maybe you haven’t encountered this in the real world?

Comment: So speculate then:  Why does VS provide parameter definition (and xml comments) and not local definitions then?  Parameters are great…. Except they are generally transformed into local entitles… Why not provide the same for local variables as well?

Comment: @Silverten: No need to speculate - parameters are part of a method's API, whereas local variables are implementation details. And no, I haven't encountered this in the real world, because I follow best practices when it comes to naming my variables and properly encapsulating my code. If you've inherited a spaghetti codebase, you have my sympathy, but there is no sense in trying to monkey-patch it with doc comments on local variables (unless you were dead serious about making things "as Verbose as possible", in which case, knock yourself out - just don't put blame on VS for not enabling you).

Comment: So, short (and long) answer is no.  It does seem like a useful thing, especially with all the other useless junk the VS team has thrown at their product.  

BTW: I don’t think that the “the variable name” and “surrounding context” quite cuts it in a lot of numerous, exhaustive, overboard,  relative, legacy, and so on and so on cases.

Comment: One final comment: I actually do use XML comments to read through my own code.  If you are not commenting your own code, (even to local variables) you are really doing yourself a disservice! And VS is really lacking!

Comment: @Yeldar Kurmangaliyev – Question --- Why is there no sense in documenting you local variables?

Comment: @Silverten Small correction: There is a sense in documenting your local variable. There is no sense in XML-documenting your local variables :)

Comment: @Yeldar – Thank you for clarifying.